# Is Ubuntu only for laptops?

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Ubuntu only work on Desktop PCs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213893/does-ubuntu-only-work-on-desktop-pcs)

I have downloaded ubuntu a long time ago on my Windows 7 PC and it didn't work properly. And now im afraid to download it on my Windows 7 lenovo laptop, because it could get ruined. Please help. and how does the usb stick ubuntu work?

Comment: Your Question's title asks for one thing, then your question's body says another, which one is it? please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

No. Ubuntu is suited for Laptops, Notebooks, Netbooks, PC, Mac, Server and many others.

[You can use DVD or USB drives to install Ubuntu.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

To install Ubuntu alongside with your Windows 7, you have 2 options:

Using [wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer) or installing in a different partition or separated Hard Disk.

The first option is the easier, since it change your Windows 7 installation.

For the second option, you need a little bit more knowledge about Hard Drives and Partitions.

Don't be afraid to ask, we can help you, no matter what option you choose.